# Proof of Stokes' Theorem in the special case of the support being contained in a single chart

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, stokes-theorem

I am currently trying to work through the proof of Stokes' Theorem given in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (2. Edition). I've understood everything for the special cases of $\mathbb{H}^n$ (the upper half space) and $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm now stuck at the following step where we assume the (compact) support of an $(n-1)$-form $\omega$ is contained in a single smooth chart $(\varphi, U) \in \mathcal{A}$, where $\mathcal{A}$ is an atlas of the manifold $M$ (found on page 413).

In equation (16.6) the book says
$$
\int_M d\omega = \int_{\mathbb{H}^n} (\varphi^{-1})^* d\omega,
$$
which does follow the definition of integrals of forms on manifolds in terms of the pullback, however, I don't understand why $\varphi(U) \subseteq \mathbb{H}^n$. In other words: Why do we assume $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{H}^n$, instead of the more general $\varphi : U \to \mathbb{R}^n$?

A possible solution I've thought about: We can construct $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{H}^n \cup (-\mathbb{H}^n)$, where I've defined $-\mathbb{H}^n := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : x^n \leq 0 \}$. Thus, we can split the integral into two, i.e.
$$
\int_M d\omega = \int_{\mathbb{H}^n \cup (-\mathbb{H}^n)} d\omega = \int_{\mathbb{H}^n} d\omega + \int_{-\mathbb{H}^n} d\omega.
$$
Since $\mathbb{H}^n$ and $-\mathbb{H}^n$ can be obtained from one another with a diffeomorphism that essentially swaps the sign of the $x^n$ coordinate, we can focus on one only and then apply that diffeomorphism, automatically giving us the remaining half of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does that solve the issue already? If not, please let me know what the correct solution to this issue is, and especially how I'm wrong.

Comment: I dont have the second edition available, but I think I found the part in the first edition. It says "let $M$ be an arbitrary smooth manifold with boundary", before the equation. If this is the same section as yours, then the chart going into the upper half space is due to $M$ being a manifold with boundary.

Comment: You do actually have access to it, as it is freely available as a pdf file on the internet, that's where I got it. However, it doesn't seem to matter, since your citation is identical to the second edition anyway. That aside, $\mathbb{R}^n$ has empty / no boundary, right. But why does that matter? As far as I know, there's nothing that would restrict us from mapping the boundary of $M$ anywhere within $\mathbb{R}^n$, so why would we demand $\partial\varphi(U) \neq \emptyset$?

Comment: This might be a pretty unhelpful answer, but that is how you define manifolds with boundary. Because of this in general manifolds with boundary are not a manfifold by the common definition. I suggest you to read the section, where those get defined/introduced, this should be in the first chapter.

Comment: I'll definitely read through that chapter again tomorrow. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: I just read through your comment again and I think the point you are missing is that if you take a manifold with boundary M and especially take some a∈∂M you won't find a homeomorphism from any neighboorhood of a into an open subset of Rn. Since any neighboorhood will contain "closed" parts, which doesn't allow us to map it homeomorphically to an open subset. (Edited there was a word missing).